# How to dynamically create columns with tidy evaluation?

Tags: r, tidyverse, across

I'd like to create variables using a specific pattern. I need to include the variable name as a tidy evaluation in the mutate function. I made a custom example below:

```
  iris %>%
  rename(Sepal = Sepal.Width, Petal = Petal.Width) %>%
  mutate_at(c('Sepal', 'Petal'), list(test = ~ . / !!sym(paste0(., '.Length'))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
iris %>%
   rename(Sepal = Sepal.Width, Petal = Petal.Width) %>%
   mutate(across(c('Sepal', 'Petal'), ~ 
              ./get(str_c(cur_column(), '.Length')), .names = '{.col}_test'))
```

-output

```
#    Sepal.Length Sepal Petal.Length Petal    Species Sepal_test Petal_test
#1            5.1   3.5          1.4   0.2     setosa  0.6862745 0.14285714
#2            4.9   3.0          1.4   0.2     setosa  0.6122449 0.14285714
#3            4.7   3.2          1.3   0.2     setosa  0.6808511 0.15384615
#4            4.6   3.1          1.5   0.2     setosa  0.6739130 0.13333333
#5            5.0   3.6          1.4   0.2     setosa  0.7200000 0.14285714
#6            5.4   3.9          1.7   0.4     setosa  0.7222222 0.23529412
#7            4.6   3.4          1.4   0.3     setosa  0.7391304 0.21428571
#8            5.0   3.4          1.5   0.2     setosa  0.6800000 0.13333333

# ...
```

---

We don't need to rename just for doing the division.  It can also be achieved by keeping the original column names

```
iris %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('Width'), ~
              ./get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'Width', 'Length')),
         .names = '{.col}_test'))
```

---

The `.` returns the value and not the column name.  So, `paste0(., '.Length')` would be pasting substring `.Length` with the corresponding column values

Answer (score 1):

For such cases I find using base R simpler :

```
df <- iris
cols <- c('Sepal', 'Petal')
df[paste0(cols,'.res')] <- df[paste0(cols,'.Width')]/df[paste0(cols,'.Length')]

head(df)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.res Petal.res
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.6862745 0.1428571
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.6122449 0.1428571
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 0.6808511 0.1538462
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 0.6739130 0.1333333
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 0.7200000 0.1428571
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 0.7222222 0.2352941
```

Comment: in a isolated case, i agree, though when processing data through a collection of pipelines (especially in production), i like to have it all done in one command.